# Does Log4jshell make my android app vulnerable? If so, how can I protect my app

Tags: android, security, log4j

Apache Log4J vulnerability https://www.csoonline.com/article/3644472/apache-log4j-vulnerability-actively-exploited-impacting-millions-of-java-based-apps.html is impacting a number of cloud services.

I am using log4j in my Android application.
How does it impact it or is there no impact at all?
I am assuming since the malicious actor could only run local scripts, it should not be an issue but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Android apps are safe since JNDI isn't available on Android. I believe the following tweet was the first online mention of the vulnerability, and on the bottom of the second screenshot it says "Java's JNDI is not available on Android".
https://web.archive.org/web/20211209230040/https://twitter.com/P0rZ9/status/1468949890571337731
(original tweet got deleted https://twitter.com/P0rZ9/status/1468949890571337731/photo/2)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The twitter link is not working anymore but I found a similar question answered recently https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/243232/does-the-log4j-vulnerability-affect-android-users